# Line filled with \dotfill doesn't appear

Tags: debugging

I'm using the `\dotfill` command inside a special indentation block but I can't see the dots

This is the relevant piece of code:

```
{\addtolength{\leftskip}{0.5\textwidth}

Nota de aceptación:\newline
\dotfill

}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't see `\dotfill`.

Comment: replace \hrule by \mbox{}\dotfill if you want dots fill

Comment: There's no `\hrule` to replace now, but do what @touhami says anyway.